# Ruby-Selenium Webdriver: Upload file without send_keys or input element

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'm attempting to automate updating my rackspace certificates with Ruby Selenium as I have over 3k to update.

The last step I have to automate is uploading the .zip file to rackspace. Unfortunately I can not use the often-quoted send_keys method for this because there is no "input" element on the page that I can find. The attachment dialog is launched from the following element:[image]

I'm using Ruby and I don't know how to integrate the Robot class that is the normal 2nd answer to this question within my ruby framework.

I'm using a Mac so I can't use AutoIT to script the event, which is the normal 3rd answer to this question

Any help doing this would be absolutely amazing. Thank you so much for any assistance you can give me regarding this situation.

Comment: Talk to Rackspace. Surely they have some reasonable way to update 3k certificates other than writing a scraping tool and dealing with their website.

Comment: You'd think so but they've never had a customer do this before :-P

Comment: Drag and drop one file manually and check elements again to see the changes it made.. which might help you.. but not sure.